# How do i make a function that returns amount of indexes that are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to make a number based Mastermind game. Trying to figure out a function that takes two lists as paramenters and if indexes in the lists are the same it should return the amount of indexes that are the same.

PS. hope you understand what i mean ;P

```
generated_number_as_list = [1,1,1,1]
guess_as_list = [1,2,1,2]

correct = right_inrightplace(guess_as_list, generated_number_as_list)

print(correct)

output >> 2
```

Comment: The problem is you havent written `right_inrightplace` yet. maybe try writing it first then come for help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun here's a solution using recursion:

```
def right_inrightplace(a, b):
    if len(a) == 0 or len(b) == 0:
        return 0

    current = 0
    if a[0] == b[0]:
        current = 1
    return current+right_inrightplace(a[1:],b[1:])
```

Comment: I like that it uses recursion. But if you where to write this line (current = 1 if a[0] == b[0] else 0) in a more readable alternative how would i go about that? ;p.

Answer (score 3):

You can use zip to compare values with corresponding indexes and then sum True which will be cast to 1

```
print(sum(x==y for x,y in zip(generated_number_as_list, guess_as_list))) #2
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote it outside of a function. Just copy the for loop in your function and return the ans value as the output.

```
generated_number_as_list = [1,1,1,1]
guess_as_list = [1,2,1,2]

ans = 0

for i in range(len(generated_number_as_list)):
    if guess_as_list[i] == generated_number_as_list[i]:
        ans = ans + 1

print(ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also:

```
a=[1,1,1,1]
b=[1,2,1,2]
print(min(len([x for x in a if x in b]),len([x for x in b if x in a])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sum` and `map` with `operator.eq`:

```
def right_inrightplace(a, b):
    return sum(map(eq, a, b))
```

Or without using additional libraries:

```
def right_inrightplace(a, b):
    return sum(x == y for x, y in zip(a, b))
```